# FreeTDS unale to authenticate with SQL Server Express 2016

Tags: sql-server, authentication, freetds

This is a bizarre one I spent most of yesterday on.

I have a PC. It has SQL Server Express running successfully on a fresh, clean Windows 8.1. SSMS and all the Windows tools work fine. I've even talked to it via ODBC with perl and restored a backup so I have data.

I have a VMWare VM running Ubuntu 16. It has FreeTDS installed on it. I can telnet to port 1433 on the PC side happily.

I have a recent FreeTDS  (v1.00.9) compiled and installed. My ~/.freetds.conf simply has:

```
[global]
        dump file = /tmp/freetds1.log
[lsql]
        host = 192.168.1.107
        port = 1433
        tds version = 8.0
```

Doing a:

```
TDSVER=7.1 tsql -H 192.168.1.107 -p 1433 -U daveh -P password -I ~/.freetds.conf
```

(Or 8.0, which I've seen used) gives me:

```
locale is "en_US.UTF-8"
locale charset is "UTF-8"
using default charset "UTF-8"
Msg 18452 (severity 14, state 1) from WINDOWS-AECP4ER\SQLEXPRESS Line 1:
    "Login failed. The login is from an untrusted domain and cannot be used with Windows authentication."
Error 20002 (severity 9):
    Adaptive Server connection failed
There was a problem connecting to the server
```

I've tried this with my Windows user and SQL Server users with the same result. I've played around with the SQL Server user permissions to no avail.

What am I mising?

Thanks!

Comment: Not the solution, but `tds version = 8.0` is not valid to answer that part of your query. Depending on your FreeTDS version, you'll probably want `tds version = 7.2` or `tds version = 7.3` depending on your version of FreeTDS (as you can see, you're over-riding it for `tsql` already). It is a long story: http://www.freetds.org/userguide/choosingtdsprotocol.htm

Comment: Now onto the actual problem: this can happen if your VM modifies `drivers/etc/hosts` in your `system32` folder, and does add a `127.0.0.1 localhost` line. Could you check that? I've seen VM software do that before. If correct, I'll post as a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I needed a SQL Server login.

Created one and it's fine. On to ODBC now.

Comment: Did you ever get a working setup between tds and sql server 2016?

Comment: Yes. In the end it was repeatably easy. I moved to SQL Server for linux which was much the same.